# packages on a build machine without permanent access to internet

Tags: node.js, npm

I am in the process of migrating a machine from an older Linux version to a newer one. We have some node projects that seem to be more difficult to transplant to the newly desired setup.

On the old machine the build script from package.json could be run without problems because node_modules is tracked by the source control.

We don't want to use that method anymore since it is not very scalable as we want to make sure we can easily upgrade all the packages for all the users at once without the hassle of putting hundreds of subfolders (from node_modules) together with various resources.

Did you encounter such issues and, if so, how did you manage it?

Can we use a global node_modules somehow to avoid multiple node_modules for each project?

Thank you!

Comment: node_modules should never be checked in to source control... what happens if you just delete the node_modules folders and do a clean install? What version of node npm etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use a global node_modules somehow to avoid multiple node_modules for each project?

There are (at least) three possibilities. Here they are in the order that I would recommend using them:

1. If Node.js does not find a package in the application's/module's own `node_modules` directory, it will check in the parent directory (`../node_modules`) and then that directory's parent directory (`../../node_modules`) etc. So if all your projects have a shared parent directory, you can put the dependencies in a `node_modules` directory. See ["Loading from node_modules folders"](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) in the Node.js documentation.
2. A second option is to set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable to the directory where you would like your projects to search for modules not found elsewhere. See ["Loading from the global folders"](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) in the Node.js documentation.
3. Lastly, it's legacy behavior, but Node.js will also search in three other locations before giving up, so you can use one of those as well: `$HOME/.node_modules`, `$HOME/.node_libraries`, and `$PREFIX/lib/node`. See (again) ["Loading from the global folders"](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) for more information.

All that said, please note that the docs also correctly say "It is strongly encouraged to place dependencies in the local node_modules folder. These will be loaded faster, and more reliably."

If you must do this, I would use the first option above and place the `node_modules` folder as far down in the directory hierarchy as you can.